# Access files in virtual machine from virtual disk files?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware-workstation

I was using vmware workstation, but I don't have a valid key anymore. I have files and data in there that I need and would prefer not to pay $250 to get a new license. Is there a way to access my vm file system from the virtual disks or export them to a directory structure that I can access in my native OS?

I checked these other questions, but they don't seem to be what I'm looking for. The second one looks like he wants to access the file system of a vm while it's running, but I cannot run mine right now.

[Convert a Windows VM to physical partition](https://superuser.com/questions/9350/convert-a-windows-vm-to-physical-partition)

[VMWare Workstation: How to access the virtual disk from the host system?](https://superuser.com/questions/67636/vmware-workstation-how-to-access-the-virtual-disk-from-the-host-system)

Comment: you can always use your VM with VMWare Player.

Comment: @FrankThomas it uninstalls vmware player when you install workstation and the vm is 64 bit, but vmware player only supports 32 bit guests

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what OS you were running, but there are several tools out there, some restricted and some not, to mount VMDKs.  Try googling "mount vmdk".

A couple for Windows:

http://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/Vmount-for-VMware.shtml#download